# Representation of float in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I was trying to understand the floating point representation in C using this code (both `float` and `int` are 4 bytes on my machine):

```
int x = 3;
float y = *(float*) &x;
printf("%d %e \n", x, y);
```

We know that the binary representation of x will be the following

`00000000000000000000000000000011`

Therefore I would have expected y to be represented as follows

- Sign bit (first bit from left) = `0`
- Exponent (bits 2-9 from left) = `0`
- Mantissa (bits 10-32): `1 + 2^(-22)+2^(-23)`

Leading to `y = (-1)^0 * 2^(0-127) * (1+2^(-22) + 2^(-23)) = 5.87747E-39`

My program however prints out

`3 4.203895e-45`

That is, y has the value `4.203895e-45` instead of `5.87747E-39` as I expected. Why does this happen. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I have also printed the values directly from gdb so it is not a problem with the printf command.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format

Comment: On what machine are you trying this? What's the host's byte order? Big endian? Little endian?

Comment: x86_64 linux machine. Little-endian.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IEEE floating point numbers with exponent fields of all 0 are 'denormalized'.  This means that the implicit 1 in front of the mantissa no longer is active.  This allows really small numbers to be represented.  See [This wikipedia article for more explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_numbers).  In your example the result would be 3 * 2^-149

Answer (score 6):

-127 in the exponent is reserved for denormalised numbers. Your calculation is for normalized numbers while your float is a denormalised float.

Denormalised numbers are calculated using a similar method, but:

1. exponent is -126
2. implicit leading bit is no longer assumed

So this means the calculation is instead:

```
(-1)**0*2**(-126)*(2**(-22)+2**(-23)) = 4.2038953929744512e-45
```

The above is python, where `**` means the same as `^`

Answer (score 1):

In details it is described http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008
This standard assumed that you shifting left mantissa until hiding first meaning bit (increasing exponent). In your case yo have expression 1+2^(-23) - then you get correct answer   4.9..E-32

Comment: Could you show working for your answer? It does not appear to be correct in regards to simply plugging in 1+2^(-23) OR the correct answer being 4.9E-32.