# Does C have to calculate out a number in scientific notation?

Tags: c, floating-point, scientific-notation

The max value of a float is 3.40282347E+38. This is equivalent to 3.40282347 * 10^38. I am wondering if I set a float equal to this, does it have to actually perform the power and multiplication to get the value to store, or is scientific notation simply the actual value?

I am writing a school project in which we are optimizing as best we can, so this is relevant to me, especially since it is within a nested loop structure.

Comment: Literal constants such as this are evaluated at compile-time, not run-time. Also, use `FLT_MAX` rather than a hard-coded constant.

Comment: ok, great to know. i'm not allowed to include the float.h header, so I can't use FLT_MAX

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271588/representation-of-float-in-c

Comment: "Can't include `float.h`..." these bizarre rules for homework make me question the education going on sometimes... I can understand telling people not to include `<unordered_map>` if the assignment is to implement a hash table, but this is ridiculous.

Comment: @DietrichEpp My guess is that some of the more bizarre rules are intended to prevent direct use of downloaded software as homework answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use literals in your source code, those literals (and mostly expression containing all literals for constant folding) are evaluated at compile time and converted to instructions like `move immediate`, `add immediate`, `move special_constant_register` etc.

For ex:

```
int a = 10, b = 0xA;
```

Here both `10` and `0xA` literals are evaluated to same value at compile time. In your case also, `double` literal or `float` literal would be evaluated at compile time and most appropriate value would be assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `3.4e38`, it is completely evaluated at compile-time.

When you write `3.4 * 10^38`, you get a completely unexpected result. This is because `^` does not mean power-of in C. It means “exclusive or”, and `10 ^ 38 == 44`. Or maybe it doesn’t compile at all, because it is evaluated as `(3.4 * 10) ^ 38`, and xor is not defined for floating points. Or it is defined, so it would be `340 ^ 10`.

Comment: thanks, that was just pseudocode. I meant 3.40282347 * pow(10, 38)

Answer (score 1):

It's all done at compile time. The following code...

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  float foo = 3.40282347E+38;
  float bar = 3.40282347e38;
  printf("foo=%g\nbar=%g\n", foo, bar);
  return 0;
}
```

Produces this in assembler. To get the assembler use the `-S` flag to gcc ie,  something like

```
gcc -S -Wall -O3 -pedantic -std=c11 scientific_notation.c
```

This is using clang. I'll snip the assembler a bit...

```
 .section  __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
  .macosx_version_min 10, 11
  .section  __TEXT,__literal8,8byte_literals
  .align  3
LCPI0_0:
  .quad 5183643170566569984     ## double 3.4028234663852886E+38
  .section  __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
  .globl  _main
  .align  4, 0x90
```

...snipped.

Note this line `.quad 5183643170566569984`. It's a constant. Also note that even though I have two of these constants in my code only one is needed by the compiler.